# Reading Database Queries into a Specific format in Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm connecting to sqlite database using python and fetching some results. However to input these results to another file I need it to be in the following format.

```
     x={
     (1,1):1, (1,2):0,  
     (2,1):1, (2,2):0, 
     (3,1):0, (3,2):1, 
     (4,1):0, (4,2):1,}
```

My database table has only two rows (id (integer) and task (integer)). So I run the query "select * from allocation" and the result I get required to be formatted as above.

For instance allocation table is as follows:

```
    id | task
    1  | 1
    2  | 1
    3  | 2
    4  | 2
```

Please Help.

Comment: What is the relationship between that format and the data in the table? How do you get one from the other?

Comment: You mean data in database? Both fields are defined as Integers.

Comment: That wasn't at all what I asked. I want to know how you get from that db table to that dict of tuples.

Comment: Sorry. Actually that's my problem. I need to get the dict of tuples using the data in the table. For the task in the table you can think it as a binary value. So if the user id is allocated to a particular task it should have 1 in the dict.of tuple if not it should be zero like wise.

Comment: Your db table has only two *columns* (rather than rows). **x** is a dictionary of counts. Column **id** can be paired with **task** 1 or **task** 2, and the dictionary counts how many times each possible pair occurs in the table. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code the commented lines at the top indicate what's needed to access the sqlite database. Since I didn't want to build and populate such a database I created the object **C** to emulate its approximate behaviour. I used **defaultdict** because I don't know how many possible combinations of id's and tasks are involved. However, this means that only non-zero occurrences are represented in the final dictionary.

```
#~ import sqlite3

#~ conn = sqlite3 . connect ( some database )
#~ c = conn . cursor ( )
#~ c . execute ( 'Select id, task from aTable' ) 

class C:
    def __init__(self,iterated):
        self.iterated=iterated
    def fetchone (self):
        for _ in iter(list(self.iterated)):
            yield _

c=C( [ ['1','1'], ['2','1'], ['3','2'], ['4','2'] ] )

from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
for row in c.fetchone():
    print (row)
    id, task = row
    counts [(id,task)]+=1

print (counts)
```

Here's the output.

```
['1', '1']
['2', '1']
['3', '2']
['4', '2']
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('4', '2'): 1, ('2', '1'): 1, ('1', '1'): 1, ('3', '2'): 1})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. This is exactly what I was looking for. And it matches to my requirement perfectly.